# unzip a file .zip.part using terminal

Tags: unzip

i have downoalded the file VSCode-linux-x64.zip.part,i want to install this program on ubuntu platform
i taped 'sudo unzip VSCode-linux-x64.zip.part -d /the folder path '
but it dosen't work i have this message 'unzip:  cannot find or open VSCode-linux-x64.zip'
thanks for help

Comment: How did you download it? The only appearance of `.part` I know of is in unfinished downloads from Firefox or some BT clients.

Answer (score 4):

.part files are usually incomplete downloads from Firefox.
It seems the file didn't download correctly and you have to restart the download.